# Javafx Hbox Как с Hbox выделить и скопировать текст?

Tags: javafx

Привет у меня есть Hbox в который я поместил Text мне нужно этот текст выделять и копировать. Возможно кто-то знает как это реализовать?
Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выделить текст в компоненте `Text` нельзя. Стандартным средством обхода данной ситуации является использование прозрачного не редактируемого `TextField` или `TextArea`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField textField = new TextField("Info text");
        textField.setEditable(false);
        textField.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;");

        Scene scene = new Scene(new HBox(new Text("Text for copy:"), textField));

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Так же стиль может быть применен через `css` файл, а не через `setStyle`